# MRTK - multiple clipping boxes for one object

Tags: mrtk

I am trying to clip a mesh with a bunch of clipping boxes from the MixedRealityToolit/Utilities/StandardShader. 
It seems like if I add more than twice the script "Clipping Box" in the scene, only one keeps working.
May any one know how can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks
R

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible out of box. The shader has to be updated to perform the calculation over every clipping box parameters. This involves adding an array vector and array matrix into the shader and then creating a new script component to fill these arrays with appropriate collider data.

See this commit and following commits, in the branch there is a "test.scene" in the root assets folder to demo.

https://github.com/Troy-Ferrell/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commit/de1a16e30f53501ef577f693d7a0e8cf61e6aef0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !! This is invaluably helpful.